# Find non-zeros block in sparse matrix and do so process

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix, which is most of its values are zeros. 
In this matrix, some groups of consecutive rows and column are non-zeros.
Each non-zero blocks are assigned an ID. Same ID can only be assigned to at most two groups. Example(look at 5 and 8):

```
         [8 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
         [0 5 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0]
         [0 0 5 5 0 3 0 5 0 0 8]
         [0 0 0 5 0 3 0 0 0 0 8]
         [0 0 0 2 4 4 0 0 0 0 8]
         [0 0 0 2 4 4 0 0 0 0 8]
```

Now, the question is that, how do you change group with same IDs to different one[The new ID can be anything]? The input matrix is numpy matrix. Here is one possible output for above matrix(one of "5"-id group is change to the 50 and "8"-Id group changed to the 66) :

```
         [66  66  0  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
         [0   50  50 50 0 0 0 5 5 0 0]
         [0   0   50 50 0 3 0 5 0 0 8]
         [0   0   0  50 0 3 0 0 0 0 8]
         [0   0   0  2  4 4 0 0 0 0 8]
         [0   0   0  2  4 4 0 0 0 0 8]
```

Comment: You can store each block area as a list of tuples (row, column) for each element or boundaries and use these lists as values of dictionary while keys would be tuple of (ID, #) where # is group number: 1 or 2

Comment: Thanks for your response. I use similar idea but it has some problems. One problem: how do you know which block are you in?  In above example, look at two groups of 5, all are mapped to same Id.

Comment: like i said you know which group of ID=5 you are in by using dict keys as tuple of (ID, #), where # is 1 or 2

Comment: more generally your data strcuture will depend on operations that you need to perform on it, so first it is better to define all necessary operations on it

Answer (score 1):

For a start, I'd try to build a dictionary by scanning the array for nonzero terms.

`scipy.sparse` does this with a `dok` format (dictionary of keys), where a key is a tuple with the `i,j` coordinates, and the value is the array value.  But for the purposes of this problem I'd make the values (5,8,etc) the keys, and the dictionary value would a list of coordinate tuples.  A `collections.defaultdict` would do this quickly.

For example:

```
dd = {8:[(0,0),(0,1),(2,11),(3,11),...], 5:[(1,1),(1,2),...]}
```

Then I'd scan the dictionary, and using some sort of distance criteria, break up the lists

```
dd = {66:[(0,0),(0,1)], 8:[(2,11),(3,11)...], 55:[...], 5:[...]...}
```

I don't think there is a way of avoiding iterating through the array several times.  A dictionary like this a flexible way of collecting and regrouping data like this.  Once the problem is better understood it might be possible to work with the array directly.  But the first step is to get working code.  Efficiency comes later.

Comment: Thanks. I have had working code for a while, similar what you mentioned. But I am not confident I've coded in best possible way.